# Border radius inside camera View in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

How can I set up a camera screen (using Expo) so that the entire screen displays the camera feed, but there's a centered box inside the camera view with padding on all sides, reduced opacity (opacity), and should display a clear and full image within that box?

[Pircture - My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWaDE.png)

[Picture - Figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuJG6.jpg)

My code: https://snack.expo.dev/@tala-coder/camera

I managed to create the box with reduced opacity and padding, but I'm struggling to apply an inner border radius to it

Expected Outcome:
I anticipated the screen to display the camera feed across the entire screen with a centered box having reduced opacity and padding around it. Inside this box, I wanted to render a clear and full image.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77521015/how-to-create-transparent-selection-area-with-css) may solve your issue too. There is no problem to use    `border-radius`     with that solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.