# How to create transparent selection area with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a UI effect where a specific area of a webpage is highlighted and the rest of the page is covered with a semi-transparent black overlay, using only CSS. What is the standard practice for achieving this effect? I'd like the highlighted area to be fully clear and interactive, while the rest of the page dimmed.

Note: I'm looking for a solution that avoids JavaScript and complex HTML structures if possible but should also be supported by the latest browser versions.

Something like this:

[image]

Could it be done with CSS for example:

```
/* Overlay that covers the entire viewport */
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Semi-transparent black */
}
```

Then I tried using mask CSS properties for the selection area but I do not know if this is best practice.

Note: the rectangle will is meant to be interactive (moving, resizing)

Update: this might be a good solution using box-shadow for the dimmed outside effect.

```
.my-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10001;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background-color: rgba(102, 179, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Dimmed background outside the rectangle */
}
```

Comment: just use a pseudo-element with a transparent background and then use an insanely large border or box-shadow with a semitransparent color...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
.box {
    z-index: 23;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border: 10000px solid rgba(45, 37, 37, 0.322);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

This is my result:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an element or pseudo-element with a transparent background-color. Then add a semi-transparent border or box-shadow to it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  border: 20vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. The element should be interactive. So i may use js later to move it around the screen or change its size. I dont see how this can be possible the pseudo element, as well as getting the proper size of selected area later. I'm looking to create something like in my image sample.

Comment: You could try with adding a resize attribute to the element

Comment: @CyberJ how about when you slap `pointer-events: none;` on the pseudo element as well ...?

Comment: @CBroe i dont think pseudo element  is the way to go at all. The element will have to be interactive, like moving, resizing, get the position and size in js.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a _pseudo_ element, you can achieve the same with a "real" one. "Resizing" the inner box, through with the underlying content can be interacted with, would be done by modifying the border width, and to move that box, you would have to move and perhaps resize the element itself then. HTML & CSS do not have anything like this built-in, so you will probably have to loosen your requirements a bit in terms of such stuff like "avoids JavaScript".

Comment: I think if the answer is updated not use a pseudo element and just a div for the selected area it could work. I added an update to my question with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want the interactive area to be only in the "hole". So you can add `pointer-events: none;` to this block and cover the rest of the space with elements inside that will have `pointer-events:`auto;`. Example:

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.frame {
  --width: 200px;
  --height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  z-index: 666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  left: calc(50% - var(--width) / 2);
  top: calc(50% - var(--height) / 2);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.frame i {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.frame i:nth-child(1) {
  inset:-100vmax -100vmax -100vmax 100%;
}

.frame i:nth-child(2) {
  inset:100% -100vmax -100vmax;
}

.frame i:nth-child(3) {
  inset:-100vmax 100% -100vmax -100vmax;
}

.frame i:nth-child(4) {
  inset:-100vmax -100vmax 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, delectus accusantium laborum maxime laudantium quos aspernatur ratione ea dignissimos odio dicta omnis voluptatibus quo sit adipisci. Ad, corporis, ex, accusantium ullam nostrum eum nisi quidem obcaecati libero veniam error consequuntur magni magnam molestiae praesentium iste expedita odio reprehenderit labore a dolorum aperiam quasi perferendis ea reiciendis temporibus sint natus atque dolores perspiciatis doloremque corrupti harum enim cumque eveniet dolor quaerat maxime. Libero, a, similique, tempora dolore optio vero amet iusto blanditiis minima autem aspernatur vel alias nesciunt quo ut aliquam natus veniam tenetur dignissimos at mollitia praesentium reiciendis enim laboriosam quae. Saepe, voluptates, omnis dolores quam aut accusantium doloremque? Earum, odio, odit dolorum optio amet ipsam voluptates quaerat non enim iusto ipsa deleniti eaque tenetur dignissimos commodi similique aliquid quo hic unde exercitationem obcaecati molestiae culpa accusamus nemo harum sed atque veritatis consectetur numquam voluptate! Minus, nam voluptatem consequuntur numquam enim mollitia earum tenetur veritatis dolor quas. Alias, provident in sunt ipsum minus asperiores sit. Rerum, ullam unde quos maxime voluptate aperiam fugit error qui cumque eligendi sunt deserunt cupiditate laudantium! Pariatur, sequi a necessitatibus facere repellendus natus illum veritatis porro ea molestiae quos in. Minima, ex, aliquam, officiis voluptates ducimus nisi nobis porro in numquam veniam quam ipsam non deleniti sequi facilis assumenda accusantium quaerat laudantium corporis officia libero quibusdam nemo omnis molestiae alias quasi architecto cupiditate dolorem provident iusto? Ipsum, beatae, deleniti, ab neque consequuntur repellendus a cumque aut nulla dolorum magnam quis natus ut dolores omnis amet quasi iste modi voluptatum expedita soluta magni aperiam libero minima asperiores cupiditate eligendi adipisci ea quidem architecto blanditiis dicta deserunt facere quam totam reiciendis molestiae. Illo, ipsam, nihil, commodi, molestiae qui voluptates dicta non ab saepe consequuntur fugit vitae atque eum eaque quos quo eligendi tempora porro dignissimos reiciendis aperiam magni distinctio dolores enim minima temporibus accusamus in vel molestias optio ipsum vero voluptas aut repellendus maiores odit culpa veniam laboriosam sit ad. Consequatur, voluptas, ipsam, tempora, fugiat ad mollitia consequuntur dolorem dicta commodi obcaecati optio delectus molestias sed voluptatum officiis rem sit quia et vero harum in aspernatur repudiandae asperiores aut similique. Quibusdam, facere, sequi, optio eaque odio in consequuntur incidunt cumque sapiente quidem saepe maiores! Temporibus, voluptate, eum sed tenetur ut quia ab eveniet deserunt at perferendis nam aut cum maxime quod repudiandae sunt recusandae quas veritatis error sint debitis nulla officia nobis maiores dolorem. Autem a deleniti debitis nam molestiae! Iste, autem eum esse debitis cum reprehenderit vel. Iure, atque, corporis, harum quaerat saepe molestiae doloribus minima necessitatibus omnis reprehenderit earum illo magnam ratione rem eveniet quo nam ea non nemo consequuntur quibusdam corrupti ad voluptate ipsam voluptates praesentium modi sapiente iste nihil id porro pariatur obcaecati officia accusamus nisi sed voluptatum tempore dolor voluptas velit explicabo suscipit dignissimos temporibus dicta hic provident? Voluptatum nam quae excepturi cupiditate nihil. Doloremque, sit, laboriosam ipsam quas nisi facere distinctio vero similique atque quos et rem autem dolores accusamus dolorum reiciendis eius recusandae. Ad, vitae, accusamus vel nulla totam harum.
```